# typescript function that returns ReturnType of callback

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I annotate a function that takes a callback, and have such function return type inferred from the callback return type?

```js
// say that callback takes a number
function takesCallback(cb: (arg:number) => infer T /* error */ ) {
  return cb(42)
}

takesCallback(x => 'foo') // should infer 'string'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can use the helper `ReturnType`, also it is necessary to rewrite the generic structure so that it can be constrained to a function

```
function takesCallback<T extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown>(callback: T): ReturnType<T> {
  return callback(42) as ReturnType<T>;
}

const res1 = takesCallback(x => 'foo'); // string
const res2 = takesCallback(x => 123);   // number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAhgawKYGcDCKA2+ARihGgDwAqiGAHlBmACZaIAUAdFygE4DmWAFyJwaMHADuYANoBdAJSIAvAD4RYMZLAq2EAsVJphlecIBKGKCB5hKATwAOGKmoDeAKESIel60j2EJGRsACwATIoorBZWNvZOLgDc7gC+7u4QCFhQ3tgAjMrI6Nh4gYZstMpqAOTAcHDV8smZYNm5WGGFqJi4+kFoFVWIeWEAzE1AA)

Comment: How about the case where the callback is a property of an object?